# Maven Release Plugin deployment of sources.jar and javadoc.jar

Tags: maven-2, maven, maven-release-plugin, maven-javadoc-plugin, maven-source-plugin

I use maven release plugin for generating release of my project. I do not want to generate Javadoc all time I build. On the other hand when I call release:perform I would like if maven would generate sources.jar and javadoc.jar and would deploy it to maven release repository. Just because I am curious how deploying source.jar can be disabled, since It looks like it is deployed by default.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the [releaseProfiles](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/perform-mojo.html#releaseProfiles) parameter (example: `src,javadoc`) to turn on one or more profiles, and in these profiles, define the source and javadoc generation:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>src</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1.2</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>attach-sources</id>
                            <phase>verify</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>javadoc</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.7</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                            <phase>verify</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>jar</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: Interesting, that it works only with the plugin version 2.1. So you have to say like: mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.1:prepare, since with default version 2.0.beta8 is not working with this -releaseprofiles argument.

Answer (score 11):

From the documentation of [Maven Release Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/perform-mojo.html), there is a `useReleaseProfile` parameter, which determines `Whether to use the release profile that adds sources and javadocs to the released artifact, if appropriate`. This is `true` by default.  You can try changing this as appropriate to enable/disable source/javadocs.

Comment: Sadly, this now appears to be "deprecated".